# How to determine PostgreSQL Error Codes from error message

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In a PL/pgSQL function, I want to trap an error. For example, when I convert text to a number, I get an error (I run it in `psql`, but get the same error in the Postico GUI client):

```
select 'a'::numeric;

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "a"
LINE 1: select 'a'::numeric;
               ^
```

To [trap this error](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING), I made an EXCEPTION-clause like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.to_number(input text) RETURNS numeric
    AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN input::numeric;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        RETURN NULL;
END
$$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
;
```

However, I don't like the condition `WHEN OTHERS`.

How do I map the error message `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "a"` to one mentioned in the [Appendix A. PostgreSQL Error Codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/errcodes-appendix.html)?

I want to catch the conversion error when converting to `numeric` and no other conditions (as the above function is a simplified one).

I have the feeling I'm missing something, but what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get the error in `psql`, run

```
\errverbose
```

and you'll get information like

```
ERROR:  22P02: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "a"
LINE 1: select 'a'::numeric;
               ^
LOCATION:  set_var_from_str, numeric.c:6856
```

`22P02` is the SQLSTATE, and Appendix A of the documentation will tell you that that is `invalid_text_representation`.